# Append to SQL from Access is dropping leading zeros

Tags: sql-server

My append query from Access to SQL is dropping leading zeros.

The "Number" is stored in an Access table with the field type of Text.  In Access the characters appear as an 8 character field (00012345).

The "Number" is being appended to SQL into a table with a field type of Char (8).

When I open the SQL table the value showing is 12345.  The leading zeros have been dropped.

Can anyone help me understand why the leading zeros are being dropped and what I can do to have the data append with the leading zeros intact.

Comment: How are you transferring the data to SQL from Access? It sounds like it is being converted to an INT, either explicitly or implicitly, so the leading zeros are trimmed.

Comment: We are exporting from Access to SQL.

One of my staff members played with this and found that if the SQL field type was changed to varchar that the leading zeros remain.  Both Char and nvarchar drop the leading zeros.    I am still seeking to understand why varchar would behave so differently than char or nvarchar.